# Extracting descriptive information from a LiDAR cloud (.las files)

Tags: statistics, geometry, gis, photogrammetry, lidar

I have .las (lidar data) file, now I wanted to know the size of it, for example how long it's width and height in kilometers.

How is it possible to retrieve these kind of info?

Comment: you want to know the size of "it"?  it sounds like you want to know the size of the file but I'm sure thats not what you're asking.  Please clatify.

Answer (score 7):

tl;dr: install libLAS and run `lasinfo myfile.las`.

Lasfile headers, in general, shouldn't be trusted since they may not agree with the true data bounds. A more robust approach is to calculate the spatial extents of the data by reading the points themselves.  Here's a few free and open-source ways to calculate the true bounds of a lasfile:

- [libLAS](http://www.liblas.org/), via `lasinfo mylasfile.las`

  - libLAS can also be compiled with [LASzip](http://www.laszip.org/) support to read `.laz` files
- [PDAL](http://www.pdal.io/), via `pdal info myfile.las`

  - PDAL can also be configured to read other types of pointcloud files, including compressed `.laz` and more
- If you want to inspect the lasfile's extents (and other properties) programically with Python, you can use [laspy](https://github.com/grantbrown/laspy)

Many of these software projects are available via package managers for your system:

- Windows: [OSGeo4W](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) includes libLAS, LASzip, and PDAL
- Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install liblas-bin` will install `lasinfo` on Ubuntu 14.04, 12.04, and others
- OSX: `brew install pdal liblas` using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)
- laspy can be installed via `pip install laspy`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `lasinfo` utility from `lastools` which will return the .las header information (including the extent):

http://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/

The `lasinfo` module in `SAGA GIS` will provide the same information:

http://www.saga-gis.org/

Answer (score 3):

You best bet is to use a specific software to find out the extent of this lidar file.

Another way you can probably do it is to look at the header section of the file (if you have the raw file), which must state the extent as well.

Otherwise, talk to the data provider (if you can´t find out the extent any other way). He probably has the software and knows the extension of your dataset.

George

Answer (score 1):

With [Fusion](http://forsys.cfr.washington.edu/fusion/fusionlatest.html), an option is the command line `Catalog` to retrieve descriptive statistics.

Suppose Fusion is installed under the directory `c:\fusion`and the las file is stored in `c:\lidar\point_cloud.las`. Write and run:

```
c:\fusion\catalog c:\lidar\point_cloud.las c:\lidar\point_cloud
```

An output example is:

[image]

Add switches to obtain more information or to adapt the command to specific needs (e.g.; switch 'coverage' will show nominal coverage area of the entire lidar cloud).